# move file from azure vm to azure file storage

Tags: azure, file

I have a Azure VM (Win 2016) where I have a folder where we have file coming every 5 minute.

Now I want to create and Window Service which will run on Azure VM and if any file exist, it will move to Azure File storage.

Could someone guide whats need to do or any other approach?

Comment: You can mount the Azure File Share to the windows VM. Follow the steps [File Share to Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows).

Comment: Thanks Charles, does mount required any piece of code or it is just a settings with Azure portal and whenever some file available within a folder in Azure VM share, it will push the file to Azure File storage?

Comment: It is just like file share in windows from the Internet. You should take some steps in the VM. And if you move the file to the mount folder then it is in the Azure storage File Share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you have 2 options:

1. Mount File Storage Share as a network drive. Once you mount the share as a network drive (and get a drive letter) you can simply use System.IO namespace to perform IO operations. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows.
2. Use Microsoft's Azure Storage SDK which is a wrapper over Azure Storage REST API and upload files from the local folder to the share in Azure File Storage. Please note that once the file is uploaded in Azure File Storage, you would need to manually delete the file from your server to achieve move operation.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, my folder is in Azure VM only, do I need to write some sort of window service? Is option 1. requires any code and just the settings?

Comment: does mount required any piece of code or it is just a settings with Azure portal and whenever some file available within a folder in Azure VM share, it will push the file to Azure File storage?